# Spring social - detect DuplicateConnectionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social

I am using spring social, spring security, spring mvc and am trying to achieve the following.

1. Have connect and disconnect buttons for several social networks on one page.
2. Ask the user if they want to merge user accounts (each registered with a different social provider) when they try to connect to a social network that already exists in my database.
3. Force the user to verify ownership of both accounts before carrying out the merge.

The difficulty I am having is with the spring social framework.

I have implemented (http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/social/connect/ConnectionRepository.html) including the add method which throws (http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/social/connect/DuplicateConnectionException.html) if an account being connected to already exists in my database.

ConnectController (http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/social/connect/web/ConnectController.html) swallows this exception in a private method and then privately converts all errors into model attributes, which means I only know if there was a duplicate connection in my jsp page.

```
${social_addConnection_duplicate}
```

I also had a look at interceptors but they only fire on connection success or before a connection attempt is made. They also apply for each provider so cannot be used globally for all providers.

Is there a fancy spring way to capture this exception in a controller somewhere that I cannot find?